# Align numbers right for any input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to align numbers right for any input. However I can't seem to do it only for a specific input not for any input. I've also tried turning the list of strings into a list of nums using `list comprehension` and then do `print("{:5d}".format(i))`. I've also tried doing something like  `print("{:>len(i)}".format(i))`

```
n = input().split()

m = sorted(n, key =int, reverse = True)


for i in m:
    print("{:>10}".format(i))
```

Sample Input:

```
8 11 12 123 45678
```

Sample Output:

```
45678
  123
   12
   11
    8
```

I've managed to do it for the input above, but not for any input.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you've posted? how does the output of that differ from your desired output? Seems to work ok for me

Comment: Can you give an example of input where it fails to work?

Comment: It has to work for any input...it aligns the text correctly only for the specified input.

Comment: try `1231231232131213 123123213213 12312321321 213123123` Does this seem right for you?

Comment: *Any input* is a bit too generic. You probably mean "positive integers of any size as input". Negative numbers will mess up the output, while strings or floats will cause an error.

Comment: Yes, probably only positive integers, however the task does not specify that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe it could generalize better by keeping your elements as strings and using [rjust()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust) ?

```py
n = input().split()
for i in n:
    print(i.rjust(len(max(n, key = len))))
```